# jQuery-iax: Cannot read property 'extension' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have done almost everything .But getting confused with this one. I want to create auto scroll using jQuery-iax . But whenever I tries to scroll page it gives the error. I am very beginner with it.

here is my code.

```js
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-ias.js"></script>

       
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $.ias({
 item: '.col-md-3',
 container: '.container',
 next: '.nav a',
 pagination: '.nav',
 delay: 600
 })
 .extension(new IASTriggerExtension({offset: 2}))
    .extension(new IASSpinnerExtension())
    .extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension())
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you loading two different versions of jQuery, overwriting the first with the second?

Comment: Okay as you said I changed 1 of them to the latest one(2.1.1) but the error is occuring as it was